# Nodejs: Consume rabbitmq messages in topic exchange

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am trying to use rabbitmq `topic exchange`. In rabbitmq web management i created a queue called **queue1** with this details :

[image]

After creating queue i used default exchange `amq.topic` and i binded **queue1** to this exchange with `anonymous.info` routing key:

[image]

After push some message to this queue1 :

[image]

Now i want to consume these messages so in order to i wrote this script:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect(uri, (error0, connection) => {
    if (error0) {
        throw error0;
    }
    connection.createChannel((error1, channel) => {
        if (error1) {
            throw error1;
        }
        var exchange = 'amq.topic';

        channel.assertExchange(exchange, 'topic', {
            durable: true
        });

        channel.assertQueue('queue1', { exclusive: true, durable: true }, (error2, q) => {
            if (error2) {
                throw error2;
            }
            console.log(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C');
            var key = 'anonymous.info';

            channel.bindQueue(q.queue, exchange, key);
            channel.consume(q.queue, function (msg) {
                console.log(" [x] %s:'%s'", msg.fields.routingKey, msg.content.toString());
            }, {
                noAck: true
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But i got this error :

```
Error: Operation failed: QueueDeclare; 405 (RESOURCE-LOCKED) with message "RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue 'queue1' in vhost '/'. It could be originally declared on another connection or the exclusive property value does not match that of the original declaration."
```

So i change `channel.assertQueue()` method  to this, means i removed queue name:

```
channel.assertQueue('', { exclusive: true, durable: true }, (error2, q) => {
    if (error2) {
        throw error2;
    }
```

Now i did not get those error but i did not any result. I have 101 messages in **queue1**?

In `channel.assertQueue` callback the result of `q` is :

`Object {queue: "amq.gen-Z7PhA8xKdA7v0H_33alxDA", messageCount: 0, consumerCount: 0}`

but i do not have this queue name `amq.gen-Z7PhA8xKdA7v0H_33alxDA`.

It is `Temporary queues` but i have a queue and i want to read from my queue.

Comment: Maybe it's a bit late for my answer, but the answer is that you should change the type of queue from 'exclusive: true' to 'exclusive: false'. Then you will be able to consume your messages. Regards

Answer (score 1):

from the snapshot your "queue1" is durable, non-exclusvie; and your code try with a queue durable, exclusive

Comment: I changed my code  to `channel.assertQueue('', { durable: true }, (error2, q) ` but still i did not get any result and queue name is something else. @yk42b

Comment: I'm not familar with node.js. However, I think you can try channel.assertQueue('queue1', { durable: true }, (error2, q) @sayreskabir

Comment: I do but i still got `Error: Operation failed: QueueDeclare; 405 (RESOURCE-LOCKED) with message "RESOURCE_LOCKED - cannot obtain exclusive access to locked queue 'queue1' in vhost '/'. It could be originally declared on another connection or the exclusive property value does not match that of the original declaration."` error @yk42b