# Nodejs: avoid from creating temporary rabbitmq queues by consumer

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq `topic exchange` to consume messages that pushed from client. So i created a queue and binded queue to default exchange `amq.topic`.

```
amqp.connect(uri, (error0, connection) => {
    if (error0) {
        throw error0;
    }
    connection.createChannel((error1, channel) => {
        if (error1) {
            throw error1;
        }
        channel.assertExchange(exchange, 'topic', {
            durable: true
        });
        channel.assertQueue('', { durable: true });
        channel.bindQueue('queue1', exchange, key);
        try {
            channel.consume('queue1', msg => {
                if (msg !== null) {
                    console.log(" [x] %s:'%s'", msg.fields.routingKey, msg.content.toString());
                }
            }, { noAck: true },);
```

But every time that amqp connected and consume messages, a `Temporary queues` created and did not delete ?

Why temporary queues in consume time is created when i have a queue? and how it is possible to avoid from creating?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Queues with random names `amq.gen-*` will get generated when you are trying to declare a queue with blank name. Issue here is you are passing blank value as the queue name. Change the same to below.

`channel.assertQueue('demo-queue', { durable: true });`

See https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html for more details

Comment: I changed to this `channel.assertQueue('queue1', { durable: true });` but i got error `Error: Channel closed by server: 406 (PRECONDITION-FAILED) with message "PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-queue-type' for queue 'queue1' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value 'classic' of type 'longstr'"` @DilvinRiyo

Comment: Are you passing 'x-queue-type' argument now ?.
Remove it if not required, otherwise please share the source code to help me further.

Comment: This is other my post that has complete code about publisher and sender and how i create queue and other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58370942/nodejs-consume-rabbitmq-messages-in-topic-exchange  @Dilvin Riyo